# Using a select with option to input text if no options are found in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I am using Rails, HAML and simple_form and I am attempting to create a select with an option to enter text if the item is not found in the collection. Is this possible? It currently looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, office] do |f|
  = f.input :person,
      label: "Select Person",
      collection: People.all,
      label_method: -> (person) { person.name },
      input_html: { data: { plugin: "select2" } }
   = f.submit "Set Person", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block"
```

Comment: you would have to fire on change event on select tag.

Comment: I presume you are using select2, looks like you can enable that feature in select2 initializer https://select2.org/tagging?